# Extract sum of values from database in java

Tags: java

I want to display sum of amount in textfield but amount fetching from database..Here I tried this code but only 0.0 displays in textfield...Dint get actual amount.

{
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
            {

```
            try
            {
                String t= (String)client.getSelectedItem();   //client = JCombobox
                String query1="select sum(Amount) as total from enquiry where client= ?";
                PreparedStatement p=conn.prepareStatement(query1);
                p.setString(1,tfsum.getText());    //tfsum = textfield whr sum will displays
                ResultSet r=p.executeQuery();

                if(r.next())
                {

                    String s=r.getString("sum");

                    tfsum.setText(s);

                }
                r.close();
                p.close(); 

            }
            catch(Exception d)
            {
                d.printStackTrace();
            }



        }
    });
```

Comment: `total(Amount)` is not valid SQL. Try `sum(Amount)`. And use your debugger and stack trace; they're there for a reason.

Comment: try `String query1="select sum(Amount) from enquiry where client= ?";`  I think the back-ticks are not needed too

Comment: @ScaryWombat They don't hurt. Maybe OP chose to use them because `CLIENT` is a keyword in MySQL (though not a reserved one).

Comment: @ shmosel, @Scary...I tried but now blank textfield are there..not even 0.0

Comment: @shmosel Yes, I type of agree.  Did not know about `CLIENT` - thanks

Comment: @G.S What do you mean?  Some exception?

Comment: Extract the from the `ResultSet` by position instead of name or give the result a name ie `select sum(Amount) as total from ...`

Comment: @Scary...no Sir, not an exception,even not an error..on form if I choose client name randomly from combobox...textfield remains blank only against clients ...so from my end not able to resolve it

Comment: Read the comment from @MadProgrammer .  Also trim the String from your textfield and ensure (by using a different tool) that data does actually exist

Answer (score 0):

Use `sum` instead of `total`. Because total is not a valid aggregate function.

Also remove backticks from your query. There is no need to put column name in backticks/quotes. Try this

```
String query1="select sum(Amount) from enquiry where client= ?";
```

Comment: Those aren't quotes, they're backticks. Some prefer to enclose column and table names in backticks.

Comment: I tried without backticks but not works...String query1= "select sum(Amount) from enquiry where client = ? ";

Comment: p.setString(1,tfsum.getText()); ......Is it correct syntax for passing values to client.?..Because tfsum is textfield name where result should display

Comment: You database driver will take care of replacing vales into SQL. Did you tried to execute this sql directly on db to get the result. One more thing, why do you need sum if you are fetching only 1 Client record

Comment: @Maverick...Same query works at sqlite database and it give correct sum..and against 1client there are multiple values in database...so Here want to display these sum of values in textfield...

Comment: In your new code, you are using `sum(Amount) as total` in SQL query but while getting result from resultset you are using **sum** in  `String s=r.getString("sum");` which is not correct.  Replace **sum** with **total** and it should work.